# How to remove duplicate rows when one row is connected to other table

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

I need to remove the duplicates that appeared in the table, however I don't know how to do it.

One of these duplicates is linked to another table by ID. I'd like to leave this record and delete all others that have the same value.

Main table: ZasobCRM
Second table: ZasobCRM_Raw

Data by time readers are sent to the table: ZasobCRM_Raw. Then, based on two entries on the same day, one entry in the table is created for the same employee: ZasobCRM.

A valid example:

```
select * from ZasobCRM_Raw where ZasobCRM_ID = 20490
select * from ZasobCRM where ID = 20490
```

Result:

```
ID  DataIMPORT  DataUTWORZENIA  string_1    string_2    string_3    string_4    Status  ZasobCRM_ID Exception
45883   2019-10-01 17:08:18.000 2019-08-01 05:57:54.000 0025    6531487 010819055634    0   WCZYTANE    20490   
45893   2019-10-01 17:08:18.000 2019-08-01 06:57:55.000 0025    6531487 010819065321    0   WCZYTANE    20490   

ID  Zad_Guid    Operator_ID Rozpoczecie Zakonczenie Nazwa
20490   c2db3bf6-6156-4dba-b802-b4064f99d7ca    2181    2019-08-01 05:56:34.000 2019-08-01 06:53:21.000 Arkadiusz Kowalczyk
```

Invalid example (duplicated):

```
select * from ZasobCRM_Raw where string_1 = '0044' and string_3 like '%29101905%' order by string_3
select * from ZasobCRM where Rozpoczecie = '2019-10-29 05:55:48.000' order by ID
```

Result:

```
ID  DataIMPORT  DataUTWORZENIA  string_1    string_2    string_3    string_4    Status  ZasobCRM_ID Exception
58020   2019-11-07 09:22:31.000 2019-10-29 05:56:38.000 0044    6531592 291019055548    0   WCZYTANE    25143   


ID  Zad_Guid    Operator_ID Rozpoczecie Zakonczenie Nazwa
24596   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24610   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24627   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24641   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24658   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24672   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24694   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24708   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24725   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24740   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24757   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24771   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24788   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24802   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24819   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24833   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24850   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24864   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24881   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24895   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24912   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24926   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24943   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24957   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24974   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
24988   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
25005   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
25019   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
25036   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
25050   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
25067   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
25081   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
25098   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
25112   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
25129   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
25143   0163c7af-16ef-4289-8a6c-e4d47c3e8dbe    2199    2019-10-29 05:55:48.000 2019-10-29 11:45:16.000 Ewa Domin
```

In the last example I did not give the second row in the table: ZasobCRM_Raw because it does not matter.
From the last example, after deleting, I should have only the row with ID: 25143

I was able to find these duplicates by query:

```
SELECT
    Zad_Guid, Operator_ID, Rozpoczecie, Zakonczenie, Nazwa, COUNT(*)    
FROM
    ZasobCRM as ZCRM
GROUP BY
    Zad_Guid, Operator_ID, Rozpoczecie, Zakonczenie, Nazwa  
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

My query does not show me which of these duplicate rows is associated with another table.

I don't know how to remove them based on it.

EDIT:

```
 delete from ZasobCRM 
WHERE Zad_Guid IN (SELECT
    Zad_Guid
FROM
    ZasobCRM as ZCRM
GROUP BY
    Zad_Guid, Operator_ID, Rozpoczecie, Zakonczenie, Nazwa  
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1)

and
(select count(*) from ZasobCRM_Raw as ZRaw where ZRaw.ZasobCRM_ID = ZasobCRM.ID) = 0
```

Worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a sub-query in Delete command.

```sql
DELETE 
FROM <tablename>
WHERE Zad_Guid IN (SELECT
    Zad_Guid
FROM
    ZasobCRM as ZCRM
GROUP BY
    Zad_Guid, Operator_ID, Rozpoczecie, Zakonczenie, Nazwa  
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1)
```

> Note: Please make sure you take a backcup before executing the Delete command.

Comment: My query does not show me which of these duplicate rows is associated with another table.

If this could be added to this query, then it would probably work with your idea